# When should lobos migrations be run?

Tags: database, clojure, database-migration

Since there isn't a leiningen plugin for lobos, Where should I run the code to deploy lobos migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be `lein repl`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a web app, you are probably using compojure and ring. In whch case, the best way to do this would be with the `:init` field, using the ring plugin.

Otherwise, of course you could set up your own init method to call before the application logic.